# How can I closing my position with using Market order via Bybit API?

Tags: python, api, bybit

I try creating a sample trading bot using python with Bybit API. it is working when I creating position but when I trying close the position it sending me error because when i closing position I cannot using "Market" order. I am searching on Bybit docs but I cannot see this point.

**let me explain:**

**it my opening position code**

```
open_position = client.place_active_order(symbol="BTCUSDT",
                side="Buy",
                order_type="Market",
                qty= 0.001,
                time_in_force="GoodTillCancel",
                reduce_only=False,
                close_on_trigger=False,)
```

**And I try closing position with this code:**

```
last_price = client.latest_information_for_symbol(symbol="BTCUSDT")["result"][0]["last_price"]

# close position
close_position = client.set_trading_stop(
                 symbol="BTCUSDT",
                 side="Buy",
                 take_profit=last_price)
```

**this code is working in some cases but generally I getting this error:**

```
InvalidRequestError(
pybit.exceptions.InvalidRequestError: Takeprofit:445890000 set for buy position should be higher 
than base_price:445895000??lastprice (ErrCode: 130027)
```

I think, the `last_price` is not equal to BTCUSDT parity price when I running order to `take_profit = last_price`

for example, my `last_price` code getting BTCUSDT= 40000 but BTCUSDT went up 40100 when my code until place an order.

So, How can I closing position with using "Market" order?

**The Bybit documantation is here [Bybit Api documantation](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/linear/#t-position)**

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 6):

I've been wrestling with the same issue until I realized that the actual way to close trades on ByBit is to use the reduce_only option with the opposite side to with which the trade was opened:

```
client.place_active_order(symbol="BTCUSDT",
                side="Sell",
                order_type="Market",
                qty= 0.001,
                time_in_force="GoodTillCancel",
                reduce_only=True
                close_on_trigger=False,)
```

Comment: thx that help me was trying to get it to work for 3h

Comment: what if a trader has several opened positions on the one side and wants to close only one position. How to do it?

Comment: @rvit34, With similiar pair in Derivates/Futures trading exchanges don't open several positions for individual position, infact new position's quantity gets added to the exisiting poisiton, so if you had BTC/USDT position opened with quantity 2, and you open a new position with quantity 3, the exisitng position's quantity will be added to 5 instead of opening a new position. only positions with different pairs are created individually.